# Best way to build a Shopify App with OAuth

Tags: php, oauth, shopify

My client would like a twitter feed that just shows her most recent tweet on her Shopify site. She needs it to be more customizable than the current standard widget provided by Twitter is.

There is a Shopify app that someone built for a monthly fee that does this, but I'd like to build it on my own.

I have already built a stand-alone solution with the Twitter API and twitterOAuth PHP library. Since I can't run the PHP on Shopify, I figured I need to build an app.

Just wanted to see if I'm on the right track or if there is a better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, RiggsFolly. I'm not looking for a tutorial by any means, just some different opinions on what people might think the best way to go about this would be. Like maybe it'd be better practice to build this using rails etc. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry but its not an opinion site

Comment: OK, back to fumbling around Google then. If you have any recommendations on where I can get opinions/best practices, etc., it'd be appreciated. Sorry for OT post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle Twitter oAuth, then clearly you can handle Shopify oAuth. As per what we can barely call standards, it turns out using oAuth is pretty much the same between all these services. So Shopify oAuth is going to pose no trouble for you. Hence it is relatively easy for you to create an App in PHP in the cloud, that scrapes Twitter, and provides said scraped Tweet to Shopify.